# Netlogo Error: "This <turtle> is already dead

Tags: netlogo

I am studying flocking behavior in netlogo, and in order to keep track of various flocks I am using a hidden "flock-holder" turtle that I can hatch or let die if a new flock is created or an existing flock runs out of members. I am coming across an issue however, where on occasion when I am trying to interface with some data within a flock, as referred to through an individual member of a flock, I get a message saying "That  is dead", causing the code to fail.

From what I understand of the "die" command, if a turtle of any kind dies, it should remove itself from any agentset or variable that references it, and therefore this sort of error shouldn't be a problem? How can I fix or at least debug this strange issue?

Code of my flock-evaluation function that is having the issues below:

```
to evaluate-flock
  if is-in-flock = True ; checking to see if a flock has died out
  [
    if get-flock-size flock-reference < 2 ; is the turtle the only one in the flock?
    [
      if verbose = True [ print "Flock has dwindled to nothing" ]
      ask flock-reference ; has no more members, so is removed.
      [
        ask flock-members
        [
          set flock-reference nobody ; clear any remaining flock members of association with this flock
        ]
        die
      ]
      set is-in-flock False ; no longer in a flock
    ]
  ]
  ifelse is-in-flock = True ; is turtle in a flock?
  [
    if verbose = True [ type "This turtle is in flock " print [ who ] of [ flock-reference ] of self ]
    if any? other preys in-radius vision with [ is-in-flock = True ] with [ flock-reference != [ flock-reference ] of myself ]; check for nearby turtles that are in different flocks
    [
      if verbose = True [ print "There are other nearby flocks" ]
      let current-school-size ( get-flock-size [ flock-reference ] of self )
      if verbose = True [ type "I am part of a school of " print current-school-size ]
      let temp-list turtle-set other preys in-radius vision with [ is-in-flock = True ] with [ flock-reference != [ flock-reference ] of myself ] with [ ( get-flock-size flock-reference ) > current-school-size ] with [ subtract-headings ( average-schoolmate-heading [ flock-members ] of flock-reference ) heading < 60]; are any nearby turtles in different, larger flocks that I am alligned with? if so, add them to a list
      if count temp-list > 0 ; does the list have any members?
      [
        if verbose = True [ print "Found a bigger flock" ]
        ask flock-reference
        [
          remove-from-flock myself ; remove myself from my old flock
        ]
        set flock-reference [ flock-reference ] of ( max-one-of temp-list [ get-flock-size flock-reference ] ); join the biggest flock on this list
        set is-in-flock True ; sets it to true in case it wasn't for some reason.
      ]
    ]
  ]
  [
    if verbose = True [ type "Turtle " type [ who ] of self print " is not in a flock" ]
    ifelse any? other preys in-radius vision with [ is-in-flock = True ] ; are there any pre-existing flocks the turtle can join?
    [
      if verbose = True [ print "There are nearby flocks" ]
      let potential-flock turtle-set other preys in-radius vision with [ is-in-flock = True ] ; grab any nearby turtles that are already in a flock
      ***set potential-flock potential-flock with [ subtract-headings ( average-schoolmate-heading ( [ flock-members ] of flock-reference ) ) heading < 60]; remove any that are not aligned with this turtle***
      if count potential-flock > 0
      [
        if verbose = True [ print "There are nearby flocks that I am aligned with" ]
        set flock-reference [ flock-reference ] of ( max-one-of potential-flock [ get-flock-size flock-reference ] ); join the biggest flock on this list
        set is-in-flock True ; turtle is now in a flock
      ]
    ]
    [ ; if there are no pre-existing flocks, turtle starts its own
      let potential-flock turtle-set other preys in-radius vision with [ is-in-flock = False ] ; Grab any nearby turtles not already in a flock
      set potential-flock potential-flock with [ subtract-headings ( average-schoolmate-heading potential-flock ) heading < 60]; remove any that that are not aligned with this turtle
      if count potential-flock > 0
      [
        if visualize-flock-creation = True
        [
          set color green
          ask potential-flock [ set color green ]
          wait 0.25
          set color blue
          ask potential-flock [ set color blue ]
        ]
        if verbose = True [ type "Number of nearby potential flockmates " print count potential-flock ]
        hatch-flock-holders 1 ; create a new flock-holder
        [
          set size 0
          set color black ; sets the new flock's placeholder color to the background
          set flock-members potential-flock ; adds the list of members to the new flock
          ask flock-members
          [
            set flock-reference myself ; asks the new flock members to add the new flock as their flock-reference 
            set is-in-flock True ; all these turtles are now in a flock
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Potentially unclear variable name reference for code above:
flock-reference: - A variable held by each flocking "prey" turtle, that just points to the hidden "flock-holder" turtle.
flock-members: - An agentset of "prey" turtles that are attached to the hidden "flock-holder" turtle.

I have added an image of the full error message below.
[image: Dead turtle error message]

Please let me know if there is any confusion about what's going on here, or if there is anything I can clarify. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us on which line of your code the error occurs?  I suspect that you are referring to prey 2 explicitly.

Comment: I have updated my original post to surround the line in asterisks.

Comment: It highlights the "of" in "subtract-headings ( average-schoolmate-heading ( [ flock-members ] of flock-reference ) ) heading"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't test this, but I expect that the error stems from agent `prey 2` having a reference to a `flock-holder` that has died.  When a `flock-holder` dies, it is (as you know) deleted from any angentsets that it was a member of and variables that hold a pointer to it are reset to point to `nobody`.  However, NetLogo is smart enough to know that this `nobody` is a dead `flock-holder` and gives you the error message you've encountered.  If after the error you inspected `prey 2`, or entered `show [flock-reference] of prey 2` at the command line, I expect that you would find that `flock-reference` was indeed set to `nobody`.

My guess is that somewhere in your code, not all the prey that were in the (now dead) flock were reassigned to another flock, but rather kept their old value of `flock-reference`, now `nobody`.  When you ask a flock to die, you might add the line `show preys with [flock-reference = nobody]`.  If there are any, you could track down why.

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: That helps, mostly because I know where it is set to "nobody". I think the error then stems from it trying to reference the "nobody", and giving me an error message that is slightly confusing. I was expecting an error message more along the lines of "There is nobody that this variable is pointing to" rather than "that turtle is dead". But I will see if this helps, thank you!

Comment: @AlpheausFeltham Once you receive an answer that solves your problem, you should accept it - that gives credit to the person who answered it, and also removes the question from the unanswered list